# jquery detect if user scroll to certain point in mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed position menu on mobile and when the user scroll to a different section the menu entry has to change.
So far I'm using this:

```
        if (scroll >= 860) {
            $('#menu_link_1').show();
        }else{
            $('#menu_link_1').hide();
        }

        if (scroll >= 1300) {
            $('#menu_link_2').show();
        }else{
            $('#menu_link_2').hide();
            $('#menu_link_1').show();
        }
```

But as the height can be different in every mobile device this is not precise, can someone show me other way to change it if the scroll has reach certain point not according to the height of the html please.

Comment: `window.scrollTop / window.height === number_of_screens_scrolled` ?

Comment: just a thing, not all the screens have the same height. sorry I'm not sure to understand

Comment: What is wrong with adeneo's answer,ITs perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using scroll-position you could check to see which element is in view. The following example might be useful - Its a bit messy but it shows how you can get the position of each 'screen' in your page and determine whether its in-view:

```
function testInView($el){
    var wTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var wBot = wTop + $(window).height();
    var wMid = wBot - ($(window).height()/2);
    var eTop = $el.offset().top;
    var eBot = eTop + $el.height();
    return (((eTop <= wMid) && (eBot >= wMid)));
}
function setInView(){
    $(".inview").removeClass("inview");
    $("div.screen").each(function(){
        var $zis = $(this);
        if(testInView($zis)){
           $zis.addClass("inview");
            $("a[href='#"+$zis.attr("id")+"']").addClass("inview");
        }
    });
}
$(document).on('ready scroll resize touchmove',setInView);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/64y6N/

Comment: Nice and efficient, but I would call all the events using `.on()` like this: `$(document).on('ready scroll resize touchmove',setInView);`

Comment: @AndersG Yes, that's cleaner. Updated my answer accordingly.